# Count consecutive instances in column

Tags: excel

I am tracking my days on duty and want excel to count the number of consecutive days on duty and post the totals next to the current date. I managed to insert a formula that does this but it counts in reverse order.  In the attached image of the file note that on `6/13/2018` it shows 28 continuous days on duty.  But that is counted from `7/10/2018` back.  I want that 28 to show up on `7/10/2018`.  So that it counts from the previous days to the current day.  Make sense????

What do I need to change in the formula to do this? Formula can be seen in the image.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNwoK.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your formula the other way around:
*If row `r-1` has the same status as row `r`, then `Counter_r` should be `Counter_(r-1) + 1`. Otherwise, restart the counter - and `Counter_r = 1`*

So, for example, in cell `E3` the formula should be:

```
=IF(D3=D2, E2+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the picture helps a bit, but I would have preferred to see the data, even though this is simple enough to reproduce.

You probably want the formula:
    =IF(AND(D2="On Duty",D2=D1),E1+1,1)

Starting in Cell E2 and copied down from there.